# Plotting a graph by grouping a column of a data frame

Tags: r, graph

I want have the following data frame

```
Value Phase
22    1
23    1
40    1
19    2
17    2
16    2
12    3
13    3
14    3
9     4
7     4
6     4
```

I want to see how the sum of `value` of a particular phase has changed over different `phases`. The `phase` column can range from 1 to 5. I want to see from phase 1 to phase 2 to 3 and so on, is there a decrease or increase in the sum of value of that phase. I want to use the base plotting system. How can I plot the graph so that the changes in each `phase` are made clear.

Comment: Since there are a multitude of values for each Phase, how do you want to measure these changes? mean? median? something else?

Comment: I want to know over different phases, the value has increased or decreased. So which measure suits best and after the measure is chosen how do I plot the graph using the base plot system

Comment: `boxplot(Value ~ Phase, data=data)` maybe?

Comment: Is the box plot the best way to make it clear whether value has decreased over phases or not? Can anything else be possible? Can a line graph or something be used?

Comment: A line plot means you have to pick a metric for each phase (median, mean, etc.) and plot only this metric. A boxplot allows you to plot both the median and dispersion indicators, which gives clues as to whether the trend is significant. Another possibility is a scatterplot + regression line. This is really a question for CrossValidated though http://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Can you tell me how do I plot a (line plot) or (scatter plot + line), if the metric I chose for each phase is the sum of values of that phase.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to do a line + scatter plot of the sums of `Value` for each value in `Phase`. First you need to aggregate the data by `Phase`. I'm providing both a base R solution (as you requested) and a ggplot solution.

```
df <- read.table(text = "Value Phase
                         22    1
                         23    1
                         40    1
                         19    2
                         17    2
                         16    2
                         12    3
                         13    3
                         14    3
                         9     4
                         7     4
                         6     4", header = TRUE)

sums <- aggregate(Value ~ Phase, df, sum, na.rm = TRUE)
png("sums.png", height = 540, width = 540)
plot(sums$Phase, sums$Value, xlab = "Phase", ylab = "Sum of Value")
lines(sums$Phase, sums$Value, type = "l")
dev.off()

# ggplot method
require(ggplot2)
ggplot(sums, aes(x = Phase, y = Value)) + geom_point() + geom_line()
ggsave("sums-ggplot.png")
```

[image]

[image]